# sklearn.transform and sklearn.fit_transform give different results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to plot my data in a 2-dimensional space using sklearn PCA. I want to re-use the same PCA representation to plot several data afterwards, but let us focus on one set first.

When I run a `sklearn.fit_transform` on my data I get the following result:

```
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components = 2, random_state = 55)
X_train_proj = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(X_train)
plt.scatter(X_train_proj[:, 0], 
            X_train_proj[:, 1], 
            c = dic[y_train.astype(int)],
            s = y_train * 10 + 1)
```

Output 1: https://i.ibb.co/B4FcV08/capture-1.png

When I run a `sklearn.transform` on the same data, using the PCA object created before thanks to the fit_transform, here is what I get:

```
X_train_proj_2 = sklearn_pca.transform(X_train)
plt.scatter(X_train_proj_2[:, 0], 
            X_train_proj_2[:, 1], 
            c = dic[y_train.astype(int)],
            s = y_train * 10 + 1)
```

Output 2: https://i.ibb.co/0MS3Jhy/capture-2.png

My data contains absolutely no NAs and is already scaled. The size, however, is quite big, as I have ~11,000 lines and ~20 columns.
I have also rapidly checked that my columns are not correlated by computing the correlation matrix.

Comment: Is `sklearnPCA` in your code an imported class of `PCA` from `sklearn.decomposition`?

Comment: Yes exactly: `from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA`

Comment: That is interesting behaviour. I do know that on large datasets, the fitting on the same data can produce different PCA instances if the random state is not specified.
But in your case the state is fixed and the PCA object is fitted only once.

I tried to reproduce your result with large dataset (similar to the sizes you've specified), but I do get consistent and reproducible results.

I recommend you to test the actual differences between the two resulting datasets, since graphical representation can be misleading, especially when the axis limits are not the same.

Comment: Checked several times, the values are completely different from one output to the other. I tried extracting the coefficients from the `PCA`object fitted with the `fit_transform` and applying them manually to my initial dataset, which resulted in the output I get with the `transform` method.

Comment: can you create some reproducible example?

Comment: You will find a dataset (in csv) on which it gives different results at the following link: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2757f68444903e6ca9a95f98664824da/X_train.csv